# How would I build a rhyming dictionary using AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, python, angularjs, dictionary

Been learning tons of AngularJS, now that I feel comfortable I've been working on a project using some Dictionary API but nothing is really working correctly...Could someone provide some value on how I would theoretically go about this?

"e.g. I type in Dime"

It'll return words that rhyme with "Dime" such as "Time" or "Hive."

Sounds simple, right? I've searched and tried finding assets and asking on Quora to you name it and StackOverflow is my last attempt!

I usually would provide some type of project and code to show why it isn't working and what I'm working on but it's not right at all and feel like a simple direction would be my key to start over.

I'm not exactly trying to build my own if there is an API to utilize but very curious overall either way!

Comment: If you want to write it yourself... good luck! If you want to use an already existing API, you can Google "Rhyming API" or try one of these: https://www.wordsapi.com/docs#rhymes or http://rhymebrain.com/api.html. Words API appears to be free for up to 2,500 requests per day.

Comment: I believe it would be better to consider phonemes instead of words.
Separate them in lists accordingly to their endings.
When the user inputs a word, get it's phonemes (somehow) and search trough the lists.

Doesn't look that simple...

Comment: Wow, quick answers and already references to APIs! I guess, why recreate the wheel if someone has already dialed it in!...Thank you guys so much.

Looking deeper in, it's a wild world with words to re-build a rhyming dictionary...sounded simple at first! Hahaha.

Comment: @mark.hch If you want to make an answer so I can check, Words API seems like my best friend. I can bootstrap with my small project MUCH faster using their tools. Cheers and thanks.

Comment: @DoPeT I fear if I make an answer it will be downvoted from elsewhere... technically the question should include some code of what was tried, and shouldn't ask about "Product or service recommendations or comparisons", per the `stackoverflow.com/tour` page, but I didn't want to leave ya hanging. I appreciate your desire to promote my rep - but I can hold off until you see me around again. Cheers.

Comment: Very true, I totally forgot about these rules! My apologies to any moderators! Thanks for the kind and quick help. Couldn't find it on Quora or anything else! Reddit wasn't very kind either... Haha :-) Cheers,